# Data2 tablo: 0 to 1 [MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

How can I change the data in the table?

**MySql Tablo:**

```
ID  --   DATA1    --   DATA2    --     DATA3   

1         test1         0               asd
2         test2         0               dsa
3         test3         0               sda
..         ..           0               ...
..         ..           0               ...
2000      test4818      0               ads
```

How can I change the data in Data2?

I want to do this;

Data2: **0  to  1**

How do I need a PHP code?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) ? You should refer to UPDATE command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a php code.

just update them.

```
UPDATE Tablo SET DATA2=1;
```

You can use this update from php too, but this is MySQLs not PHPs business.

Answer (score 0):

> Data2: 0 to 1
>   How do I need a PHP code?

No you didn't need a php code. Use the [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statement to do this like so:

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET Data2 = 1
WHERE Data2 = 0;
```